# Не отправляется почта через smtp яндекса

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

Запрашиваю доступ через yandex авторизацию на отправку писем через yandex smtp.
Получаю `access_token` когда юзер регается и через него уже получаю почту юзера по токену, потом отправляю саму почту/рассылку через его почту.

Я зарегистрировал приложение на определенный аккаунт(1@yandex.ru далее), когда я прохожу авторизацию через 1@yandex.ru, почта с него отправляется, но как только я авторизируюсь с другой почты - выдает ошибку, что у аккаунта нету доступа

```
code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: This user does not have access rights to this service ...',       
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2'
```

Как такое может быть, если я запрашиваю права при авторизации и они уже вшиты в токен

Это транспорт:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.yandex.ru",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        method: "XOAUTH2",
        user: email,
        clientId: "d2f13d7f54....",
        clientSecret: "56bd7fae1c.....",
        accessToken: "AQAAAABRe-tlAAhM.....",
    }
  });
```

Так я отправляю почту:

```
await transporter.sendMail({
    from: email,
    to: "2@yandex.ru",
    subject: 'Подписание документов',
    html: `
    <div>
        привет
    </div>
    `
  });
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь отправить письмо от 2 юзера с почтой 2@yandex.ru с `access_token` от первой ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin пытаюсь отправить почту с 1@yandex.ru (с которой и получал токен. также на эту почту зарегистрировано приложение) на 2@yandex.ru
Но когда я авторизируюсь под другой почтой, и беру токен от нее, то в nodemailer пишет, что нету прав

Comment: `from: email` тут в `email` приходит  1@yandex.ru?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin да, как раз-таки с 1@yandex.ru все окей работает, я так понимаю потому что на нее зарегано приложение, но тогда как мне отправлять почту с чужих мэйлов, от которых у меня есть токен и права на отправку почты по этому токену

Comment: ну для того чтобы отправлять с другой почты вам также надо подставить `accessToken` от этой почты в `transporter`. Сейчас же у вас в нем токен от почты 1@yandex.ru.